# Add a variable in RegExp

Tags: javascript, regexp-replace

I would like to use a variable in RegExp in this function.

```
checkSocial(platform, link) {
let reg = new RegExp(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(www\.facebook\.com\/)(?:\S+)/);
return reg.test(link);
}
```

Doing this:

```
let reg = new RegExp(`/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(www\.${platform}\.com\/)(?:\S+)/`);
```

or this:

```
let reg = new RegExp('^(?:https?:\/\/)?(www\.' + platform + '\.com\/)(?:\S+)');
```

didn't work. How can I add a variable?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "didn't work"? What exactly didn't work?

Comment: The comparison between link and the reg expression. 
When i use facebook hardcoded(first example) it works, but when i use a variable with value "facebook" it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the slashes when creating `RegExp` this way, it will add them automatically.

Also, note you would need extra escaping - I think the last `\S` token was not escaped properly?

This seems to be a more valid pattern:

```js
let platform = 'facebook';
let reg1 = new RegExp(`^(?:https?:\/\/)?(www\.${platform}\.com\/)(?:\S+)`)
let reg2 = new RegExp(`^(?:https?:\/\/)?(www\.${platform}\.com\/)(?:\\S+)`)
console.log("1", reg1) // Outputs: /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(www.facebook.com\/)(?:S+)/
console.log("2", reg2) // Outputs: /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(www.facebook.com\/)(?:\S+)/
```